# Chrome 61.0.3163.100 suddenly stops scrolling when using middle mouse button in "virtual-scroll" tables like slickgrid

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, chromium, slickgrid

When using the **middle Mousebutton (click once and drag)** to scroll the table, the browser reliably stops scrolling after a second. This only happens in Chrome's latest build (61.0.3163.100), it definitely did not happen before.

Slickgrid Demo to illustrate the problem. http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html

Does anyone know what causes this? It is not a slickgrid specific problem. I noticed this behaviour with several other virtual-scroll table frameworks.

Comment: Noticed that affect is only apparent when clicked over the data. Try it in the blank area to the right and it continues to scroll.

Comment: I noticed that as well. In my component however there are no blank areas so there is no way around this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=769390

Answer (score 0):

This happened by using jquery smooth scroll library outdated version.
I got solution from here,
[forum help](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=769341)

Now Updated version you get from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-smooth-scroll/2.2.0/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js),

Hope this solution solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately that is not the problem in this case. I'm not using jQuery smooth scroll. The problem only occurs when using the mousewheel-click-scroll technique on virtualscroll-tables.